# can these foreach loops be combined into one?

Tags: c#, linq

I have these three for loops

```
    foreach (var entityView in entitiesWithLookups)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> fieldNamesForAttributeLookup = entityView.Attributes.Where(x => x.Type == DataType.Lookup)
            .Select(x => x.InternalName);

        var entityRegistrationsWithLookups =
            ReadEntityRegistrations(entityView.InternalName, DateTime.Now);

        foreach (var entityRegistration in entityRegistrationsWithLookups)
        {
            foreach (var fieldName in fieldNamesForAttributeLookup)
            {
                output.Add(new ReferenceView()
                {
                    EntityName = entityView.InternalName,
                    ForeignKey = long.Parse(entityRegistrationView.Attributes[fieldName].ToString()),
                    ValidFrom = entityRegistration .ValidFrom,
                    ValidTo =  entityRegistration .ValidTo,
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

The three foreach loops is used to get the parameter needed to create an `ReferenceView` and add it to an output list.

Is it somehow possible to optimize this?

I tries using resharper and got this

```
from entityView in entitiesWithLookups
                let fieldNamesForAttributeLookup = entityView.Attributes.Where(x => x.Type == DataType.Lookup)
                    .Select(x => x.InternalName)
                let entityRegistrationsWithLookups = ReadEntityRegistrations(entityView.InternalName, DateTime.Now)
                from entityRegistration in entityRegistrationsWithLookups
                from fieldName in fieldNamesForAttributeLookup
                select new ReferenceView()
                {
                    EntityName = entityView.InternalName,
                    ForeignKey = long.Parse(entityRegistrationView.Attributes[fieldName].ToString()),
                    ValidFrom = entityRegistration.ValidFrom,
                    ValidTo = entityRegistration.ValidTo
                }).ToList();
```

but is this really optimized?
It does not seem very readable?

Comment: if you have to iterate through two collections there isn't a 'better' way of doing it than just iterating through the two collections. Your code seems decent and readable. I would say the LINQ query syntax is less readable and more importantly, probably harder to change.

Comment: The loops syntax is also way easier to debug, even if the linq syntax isn't that bad.

Comment: You should probably eager-evaluate `fieldNamesForAttributeLookup` to a `List<String>` for performance.

Comment: Your two code samples aren't equivalent, one uses `entityRegistrationView` three times, and the other uses `entityRegistration` twice. What is the relationship between the two?

Comment: Does your code reference a database, or is this all local data? A combined LINQ query may be preferable if you are generating multiple database queries in your loops.

Comment: @Dai why do you think creating a `List<string>` would be helpful?

Comment: @NetMage Because otherwise the `fieldNamesForAttributeLookup` Linq expression would be reevaluated on every try, including filtering with `Where`. Granted, it depends on what the underlying data looks like - it may be advantageous to _not_ materialize it as a list (e.g. if the `Where` filter only removes a few percent of the source items that are already loaded into memory, or if the source value list is concurrently mutating).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use LINQ for this so it will be smth like this.

```
foreach (var entityView in entitiesWithLookups)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> fieldNamesForAttributeLookup = entityView.Attributes.Where(x => x.Type == DataType.Lookup true)
                .Select(x => x.InternalName);

            var entityRegistrationsWithLookups = new ReadEntityRegistrations(entityView.InternalName, DateTime.Now);

            output.AddRange(entityRegistrationsWithLookups.SelectMany(
                   entityRegistration => fieldNamesForAttributeLookup
                    .Select(fieldName => new ReferenceView()
                    {
                        EntityName = entityView.InternalName,
                        ForeignKey = long.Parse(entityRegistrationView.Attributes[fieldName].ToString()),
                        ValidFrom = entityRegistration.ValidFrom,
                        ValidTo = entityRegistration.ValidTo,
                    })));
        }
```